# How to include hyphenated words in this regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the following regex to get all words (searching in a LateX table):

```
\b(?!&\b)\w+
```

Given the following example

```
& test&test-one & & \\
& & test-3& & & & & \\
```

I get this output `["test","test","one","test","3"]`

How may I change the expression so it considers hyphenated words as a word? Ie, giving the following output `["test","test-one","test-3"]`?

(I've seen some other similar examples but I'm struggling to make this work)

This can be tested at https://regex101.com/r/xZZRSC/1

Comment: Like this `\b(?!cat\b)\w+(?:-\w+)*` but your regex link has a different pattern `(.|\s)*\S(.|\s)*`

Comment: Sorry, the expression was wrong. Now I have the right expression.

Comment: You just want `\w+(?:-\w+)*`

Comment: Right, but with that solution my code "line = re.sub(regex, r"{\\textbf{\g<1>}}", line)" doesn't work. Is it possible to maintain the groups?

Comment: Just saw your comment on my answer. You can also try iterating with line.split("&"), i think you would learn more or read up on some regex basics.
re.sub((\w+(?:-\w+)*), r"{\\textbf{\g<1>}}", line)

Just put another set of brackets around it so it becomes a capturing group